# Python : Made code, doesn't know why it works

Tags: python

### I made code that reverses a string but I don't know why it works. Would greatly appreciate if someone could help explain in detail.

```
str = 'hello'
newstr = ''
count = -1 
for i in range (len(str)):
    newstr += str[count]  
    count = count - 1

print (newstr)
```

Comment: take a look at string-indexing and you will figure it out

Comment: How did you write the code then..

Answer (score 2):

Execute your script in a Python debugger as follows:

```
$ python -m pdb script.py
```

and use (s) and variable names to understand how does it work.

Answer (score 0):

This program works because you are reading the `str` from the last element to the first. Your `count` variable points to a given element and decreases its value. In Python, negative indices mean reading from the last element.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple if you take it one bite at a time. In python, setting `count = -1` means that you want to take the last item in your string ( which can be seen as an array of characters). Your `for i in range (len(str)):'` means that you are looping based on the length of your string. The line `newstr += str[count]` will add the last letter of the string to an empty string. ( so if the word was "apple", it would ad an 'e' to `newstr` ). finally, your `count` variable will decrement each time the loop is performed, which will allow you reverse your string.

Example:

```
         myStr = "apple"
         count = len(myStr) // length is =  5
         myStr[count]   // this means that it will access the fifth letter
         count = count - 1  
         myStr[count] // now it is accessing the 4th letter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stri = 'hello' # Make string stri
newstr = '' # Make string newstr
count = -1 # make int count
for i in range (len(stri)): # setting i to 0,1,2,3,4 -> this is a loop
    newstr += stri[count] # Add letter to newstr from last letter to first
    count = count - 1 # making count go down 

print (newstr) # print "olleh"
```

Dont use str as variable name, because it's a build in function